# How to access a Gradle configurations object correctly

Tags: groovy, gradle

First off, this is my first foray into Gradle/Groovy (using Gradle 1.10). I'm setting up a multi-project environment where I'm creating a jar artifact in one project and then want to define an Exec task, in another project, which depends on the created jar. I'm setting it up something like this:

```
// This is from the jar building project
jar {
  ...
}
configurations {
  loaderJar
}
dependencies {
  loaderJar files(jar.archivePath)
  ...
}

// From the project which consumes the built jar
configurations {
  loaderJar
}
dependencies {
  loaderJar project(path: ":gfxd-demo-loader", configuration: "loaderJar")
}
// This is my test task
task foo << {
  configurations.loaderJar.each { println it }
  println configurations.loaderJar.collect { it }[0]
  // The following line breaks!!!
  println configurations.loaderJar[0]
}
```

When executing the `foo` task it fails with:

```
> Could not find method getAt() for arguments [0] on configuration ':loaderJar'.
```

In my `foo` task I'm just testing to see how to access the jar. So the question is, why does the very last println fail? if a Configuration object is a Collection/Iterable then surely I should be able to index into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Configuration` is-a `java.util.Iterable`, but not a `java.util.Collection`. As can be seen in the [Groovy GDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) docs, the `getAt` method (which corresponds to the `[]` operator) is defined on `Collection`, but not on `Iterable`. Hence, you can't index into a `Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks @peter. I was looking at the API for `ConfigurationContainer` (which does extend `Collection`) and not `Configuration` which doesn't, as you pointed out.